# Name of the control - .Net Maui

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, controls, maui

I need to create the control in the class code, not in `Xaml`. I create the control as follows:

```cs
Button button = new Button
{
  Text = "Click to Rotate Text!",
  VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
  HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center
};
```

My question is, how do I assign a name to the control as you would in Xaml with `x:Name`?

I tried with all properties but there is no adequate one.

Comment: You can identify Button control using the  'button' when you create it

Answer (score 3):

The XAML `x:Name` maps to the element's `StyleId` property.  So, for example, to set the name to "MyButton":

```
Button button = new Button
{
    StyleId = "MyButton",
    Text = "Click to Rotate Text!",
    VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
    HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center
};
```

From the [`Element.StyleId`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Element.StyleId) docs:

> Gets or sets a user defined value to uniquely identify the element.

See also: https://learn.microsoft.com/answers/questions/939731/can-styleid-property-be-used-reliably-to-access-xa.html

Depending on your needs, you may or may not still need to assign the control to a custom field, as shown in [FrekyAli's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74884625/name-of-the-control-net-maui/74884742#74884742).

Answer (score 1):

When you create a XAML and use the x:Name attribute for a control it basically creates a private field for your control in the xaml.g.cs (Autogenerated).

Something like this would be a replica:

```
private readonly Button buttonName;
public YourPage()
{
   buttonName = new Button();
   this.Content= buttonName;
}
```

of this XAML

```
<ContentPage>
   <Button x:Name="buttonName"/>
</ContentPage>
```

Obviously this is simplified for readability.